# Confusion about binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^{22}$ in the expansion of $(1-3x)(1+x^3)^{10}$.

I know first the terms $x^{21}$ and $x^{22}$ will be calculate but the can't calculate the latter

Comment: I think you mean $x^{22}$.

Comment: So you have found the coefficient of the $x^{21}$ term of $(1+x^3)^{10}$? What is it? And are you having trouble with the $x^{22}$ term of $(1+x^3)^{10}$? What troubles?

Comment: You can edit the question to explain it further. Notice that people use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to write the math so that it can be read more easily.

Comment: It might help to recognize that $(1+x^3)^{10}=1+\color{grey}{0x+0x^2}+10x^3+\color{grey}{0x^4+0x^5}+45x^6+\dots$

Comment: That's correct, there is not an $x^{22}$ term present in $(1+x^3)^{10}$...

Answer (score 3):

From $$(1+x^3)^{10}$$ we have that

- **there is** one term: $ax^{21}=\binom{10}{3}x^{21}$;
- **there is not** any term for $x^{22}$ since $22$ is not a multiple of $3$.